# Javascript: sync with server

Tags: javascript, server, synchronization, datetimeoffset

I want to sync with my server and found some code (which may be a starting point for my own):

```
var serverDateTimeOffset
function getServerDateTime() {
    if (serverDateTimeOffset === undefined || serverDateTimeOffset === null) {
        serverDateTimeOffset = 0; //while syncing with the server, do not start a new sync, but return localtime

        var clientTimestamp = (new Date()).valueOf();
        $.getJSON('/getDateTime.ashx?ct=' + clientTimestamp, function (data) {
            var nowTimeStamp = (new Date()).valueOf();
            var serverTimestamp = data.serverTimestamp;
            var serverClientRequestDiffTime = data.diff;
            var serverClientResponseDiffTime = nowTimeStamp - serverTimestamp;
            var responseTime = (serverClientRequestDiffTime - nowTimeStamp + clientTimestamp - serverClientResponseDiffTime) / 2

            var syncedServerTime = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - (serverClientResponseDiffTime - responseTime) / 2);
            serverDateTimeOffset = (serverClientResponseDiffTime - responseTime) / 2;

            console.log("synced time with server:", syncedServerTime, serverDateTimeOffset);
        })
    }
    return new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - serverDateTimeOffset);
}
```

But I do not understand what is the meaning of the variable responseTime (and the logical reasoning behind it). What does it represent? Anyone has suggestions? It appears that it combines some relative with absolute times.

Example in my reasoning:
10 start at client ==+5 (req in transit) ==> 15 (arrival) ==> (server processing +5) ==> before sending (20) ==+7 (resp in transit) ==> 27 (back at client). Calculation for responseTime would result in -19/2 = -9.5.

When receive time is same as sent time at server (server processing would be 0) then 5 -22 + 10 -7 responseTime resulsts in -14/2 = -7.

And what about the variable serverDateTimeOffset?

Do I miss something? I found a description of NTP which may be helpful:

> Synchronizing a client to a network server consists of several packet exchanges where each exchange is a pair of request and reply. When sending out a request, the client stores its own time (   ) into the packet being sent. When a server receives such a packet, it will in turn store its own time (   ) into the packet, and the packet will be returned after putting a transmit timestamp into the packet. When receiving the reply, the receiver will once more log its own receipt time to estimate the travelling time of the packet. The travelling time (delay) is estimated to be half of "the total delay minus remote processing time", assuming symmetrical delays.

Edit:
The function is polled regularly (it is part of the update() function, so the first time it may indeed be 0)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
setTimeout(function () { update() }, 2000); }
..
});
```

Some tests resulted in the following examples:

> responseTime= (serverClientRequestDiffTime( -578 )-nowTimeStamp( 1621632913398 )+clientTimestamp( 1621632913081 )-serverClientResponseDiffTime( 895 ))/2= -895

> serverDateTimeOffset=(serverClientResponseDiffTime( 895 )-responseTime( -895 ))/2= 895

added req delay via proxy:

> responseTime= (serverClientRequestDiffTime( 2456 )-nowTimeStamp( 1621632992161 )+clientTimestamp( 1621632988800 )-serverClientResponseDiffTime( 905 ))/2= -905

> serverDateTimeOffset=(serverClientResponseDiffTime( 905 )-responseTime( -905 ))/2= 905

Comment: That code is broken. `serverDateTimeOffset` will _always_ be `0` when the value is returned.

Comment: I added the function for completeness.

Comment: That doesn't really fix the issue. The callback you pass to `$.getJSON()` will be executed after the result is returned from the server. This is an asynchronous operation so your code will just continue to return that new date, before `serverDateTimeOffset` is set in the callback. As a result, `serverDateTimeOffset` will have the value `0` because that is what you set it to before  you invoke `$.getJSON()`. (At least the first invocation of `getServerDateTime()` when the if-branch is entered. Subsequent invocations will return the `serverDateTimeOffset` of the first invocation.)

Comment: You are right. I checked it and it is set via setTimeout to be called regularly.